# In Project Server 2016 / PWA, are "Enterprise" things truly enterprise, or are they site collection scoped?

Tags: 2016, project-server, pwa

In the environment that I am working on, our server is set up so that the Project Web App I have to mess around in and test things in is at the URL:

```
https://servername/pwa/my-pwa
```

where the "/pwa/" is essentially a managed path, similar to SharePoint "/sites/", and the "/my-pwa" is similar to the root of a SharePoint Site Collection.

Based on my knowledge of how SharePoint Site Collections work, I am assuming that any projects uploaded and/or published to

```
https://servername/pwa/my-pwa
```

will not be visible in another site collection (Project Web App?) at

```
https://servername/pwa/another-pwa
```

Is that assumption correct?  And what about "Enterprise" calendars and custom fields?  Are they truly "Enterprise" in the sense that any enterprise calendars would be visible to all site collections?  Or are they more site collection scoped, and an enterprise calendar in

```
https://servername/pwa/my-pwa
```

would not be visible in

```
https://servername/pwa/another-pwa
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming that any projects uploaded and/or published to https://servername/pwa/my-pwa will not be visible in another site collection (Project Web App?)**

Yes, you are right, Each published project should create a **Project Site** (subsite) below its PWA instance (Site Collection) Based on the setting of "[Site Creation Settings](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/22/missing-site-creation-setting-in-project-server-2016/)" in PWA Setting, and the Project Sites will not be visible to another PWA Instance (Site Collection).

You can check the Created Project Sites, at the `Site Content` of the PWA instance site collection

[image]

---

**What about "Enterprise" calendars and custom fields?**

Enterprise calendars and custom fields will not be visible to another PWA Instance (site collection), It's 'PWA instance' (Site Collection) Scoped! Meanwhile, it will be reflected for all Projects below the current PWA Instance.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about the connected SharePoint sites (and even how you can make a subproject have a sub-site to it's master project's site), but I was a little unclear on how far "Enterprise" really stretched...

Answer (score 1):

M.Qassas has the right answer. Just to add a bit, the "enterprise" vocabulary comes from project server, not SharePoint. People can use Project Pro by itself, without project server. When used that way, people can do quite a bit with one individual project, but can't view what's going on across multiple projects. So, an "enterprise" field in Project Server is a field definition that is available to all projects (all projects in the same PWA instance, that is).

Likewise, "enterprise calendars" allow managers to manage the schedules of multiple resources across multiple project plans, something that Project Pro can't do on it's own. But again, this is all within one PWA instance. An enterprise calendar that is configured in one PWA instance is not available to another PWA instance.